# How to set a loader or skeletor for every single card item?

Tags: reactjs, loader

I want to set skeletor for my every single blog item. How can i write this code. My Code Was.

```
<div className="grid sm:grid-cols-3 gap-[3rem]">
          {blogs.map((blog,index)=>{
            return(
              <>
                {loading ? (<Skeleton/>) : (
                  <BlogCard
                    key={index}
                    id={blog.id}
                    title={blog.title}
                    thumbnail={blog.thumbnail}
                    description={blog.description}
                    tag={blog.tag}
                    category={blog.category}
                    created_at={blog.created_at}
                />
                )}
              </>
            )})}
        </div>
```

But its not working as I want.

Kindly help me please.

Comment: What's the problem. Could you explain more ?

Comment: @Amirhossein yes broo. I want to make pre loader or skeletor for my every single blog card. And I thought I can write the code between the map method and then conditionally render skeletor or blog card . But it was not showing the result that I want. Your can see my code from above.

Comment: I see but I don't understand what's the desired result and what's the result you're getting.  You want to show the loading for each blog card if your state is in loading ? What's your output now ?

Comment: @Amirhossein Blog card loaded successfully but skeletor not showing at the beginning. Though my condition work perfectly but it not returned me the <Skeleton/>

Comment: It this problem solved

Comment: @Azzy Noo Brother.

Comment: @A4ArifDev I included a possible solution, if it helps you consider upvoting / marking it as answered, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blogs will have no elements when loading, so `<Skeleton/>` wont show

put a seperate placeholders with expected no of blogs

```
const expectedBlogs = 7;
// can chance this to show the loader for previous no of blogs/per page items
const placeholderBlogs = Array.from({ length: expectedBlogs }, (_, i) => i);


  <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-3 gap-[3rem]">
         { // when loading show the Skeleton for each blog
          loading ? 
            placeholderBlogs.map((_, idx) => (<Skeleton key={idx} />)) 
           : (
             blogs.map((blog,index) => {
               return(
                  <BlogCard
                    key={index}
                    id={blog.id}
                    title={blog.title}
                    thumbnail={blog.thumbnail}
                    description={blog.description}
                    tag={blog.tag}
                    category={blog.category}
                    created_at={blog.created_at}
                />
            )})
           )
         }    
        </div>
```

Hope it helps